# How to filter the the odata query with case insensitivity when already using a function?

Tags: angularjs, odata

I have a complex odata query that I am passing through Angular using OdataAngularResrouce library. As we all know that odata queries are case sensitive and obviously I dont know how the data is being stored in the database. Here is the predicates that I used to build the query.

```js
var predicFirstName = new $odata.Predicate(new $odata.Func("startswith", "FirstName", new $odata.Func("tolower", $scope.searchObject.searchString)), true);
            var predicLastName = new $odata.Predicate(new $odata.Func("startswith", "LastName", new $odata.Func("tolower", $scope.searchObject.searchString)));

**OData URI:**
https://localhost/app/TylerIdentityUserAdministrationService/Users/$count/?$filter=((startswith(FirstName,tolower(Fahad)))%20or%20startswith(LastName,tolower(Fahad)))
```

As you can see, I want to put a function to check only the given string with startswith. I have seen several posts where the solution is to put the tolower(). However, when I put it the way mentioned above its not returning any data. Can anybody help here?

Thanks
-Fahad

Answer (score 1):

Both the properties and the literal strings in the `$filter` need to be converted to lowercase. And since the literal strings originate on the client, you can optimize by converting them to [lowercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) *before* you send the OData request.

```
$filter=startswith(tolower(FirstName),'fahad') or startswith(tolower(LastName),'fahad')
```

Note that the literal strings must be surrounded with single quotes in the filter expression.